# I've got a old school chrome bike serial number starts with AV can you please identify what kind of bike I have

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

These are pictures showing the front of the bike and rear.

Please let me know if you can identify this bike.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Anyone have a clue

Comment: Based on the headset, I'd say that that frame is definitely not old school. Less than 10-15 years most likely.

Comment: Fixed tags  to identify this bike. It's definitely not a road bike either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell what BMX frame I have?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/how-to-tell-what-bmx-frame-i-have)

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

- Its either a tiny frame or a large bottom bracket housing.  I'm guessing its for a one-piece crank, aka an Ashtabula crank.
- The frame has track ends so its intended as a single speed or an IGH, not a derailleur bike.
- The tab above the RHS of the BB, and under the RHS seatstay are probably for a chainguard.
- Lack of cable stop braze-ons suggest its for a rear coaster brake - can't see a brake bridge between either set of stays.
- The cups on the headset look surprisingly modern.

If there was a fork with it we could see more hints, but I guess its a beach cruiser, something similar to this:

[image]

It could be a nice casual bike, but you need a lot more parts, which cost a lot.  I doubt its a BMX.

Comment: I think the frame is tiny, due to the headtube length.